# Ordering is wrong when sorting favourites by date added

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

I've just been looking at my [Stack Overflow favourites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450?tab=favorites#tab-top) sorted by date added to favourites. I think the ordering is wrong because the **[Ruby on Rails: How do you check if a file is an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224379/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-check-if-a-file-is-an-image)** question was asked today and I added it to my favourites today, so it should appear first.

I suspect that it's actually ordering by recent activity, because **[Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)** was asked on 3 January but had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2224741#2224741) added 35 minutes ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: you're right -- bugfix going in now.

It was tying to the latest favorite by ANY user, not you specifically. Which made it superficially look correct as long as you were the LAST person to favorite something.

Answer (score 0):

This morning the ordering is different again! This feature is definitely busted.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean: "This bug is definitely a feature."